# Push to a new git after rebase

Tags: git, rebase

I have an existing git repo and I want to push all hashes(commits) from existing git repo to a new git repo that already has at least one hash(commit).  So I would like to do the following:

1. git pull against existing git repo
2. rebase using new git repo
3. push to new git repo

What are the exact git commands I need to do in sequence?

Comment: Please try to use correct git terminology (you cannot push a "git" and there are no "check in"s). If you don't know how things are called, avoid git concepts entirely and describes what you want to do with examples, this should avoid the XY problem.

Comment: What have you already tried to get this working? And is the existing remote commit the same as the first commit in the local repo?

Comment: See my comments below.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

*I will assume that you will deal with possible rebase problems yourself*

*I will assume that there is at least one common ancestor **suitable as a merge base**, otherwise you will have to deal with this problem before following these steps*

---

I will add some intermediate steps to your proposed approach

1. Add remote repo (`new-repo`) to the `old-repo`
2. Fetch data from `new-repo`
3. Rebase `master` branch onto the `master` branch from `new-repo` (proceed with other branches in a similar fashion)
4. Push the updated branches to the `new-repo` repository

Question you might want to answer beforehand:

- Wouldn't it be easier to merge the two?

---

1. Add `new-repo` as remote

   ```
   $ git remote add new-repo <url-to-new-repo>
   ```
2. Fetch data of `new-repo`

   ```
   $ git fetch new-repo
   ```
3. Rebase `master` (current branch and up-to-date) of `old-repo` onto `master` of `new-repo`

   ```
   $ git rebase new-repo/master
   ```
4. Push to `new-repo`

   ```
   $ git push new-repo master:master
   ```

Comment: thanks, I did something very similar at the end: 1. git checkout origin/master   2. git remote add <new git repo>   3. git fetch --all    4. git rebase <new git repo>/master   5. git push HEAD refs/heads/master